# Can I view the implementation of existing Analytics Segments? And if yes, how?

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

I created a custom report using the "All visits by page" Segment under the "By page" Dimension.

The results, however, have left me wondering; is there any way to access the code that generates the graph's data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sitecore is not open source system, your best option would be to use .Net decompiler (e.g. [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)) to peek at the implementation. "By page" dimension is located in *Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.dll*.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I've done and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can any one knows How these values are calculated in sitecore from reporting database by combining the tables.(Need SQL query to get the values).

Page Views
Visits 
Time on site 
Pages per visit 
Visits per person
Bounce rate

Comment: Particularly for the campaign

Comment: Hi, you need to decompile Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.dll with dotPeek to get to the lower-level details of how those values are calculated.